# Is there a possible way to boot into a USB media like in the advanced startup menu via command prompt?

Tags: windows, bios, uefi

I have seen people booting removable UEFI USB devices like Windows 10 installer, Ubuntu installer, etc… In Windows 10, 8.1 and 8 by entering to a menu called "Advanced Startup".

I only know how to enter BIOS menu by adding `/fw` switch to `shutdown.exe` command.

Is there a possible way to boot into a USB media like in the advanced startup menu via command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Win8. Shutdown -r -o

/o
Go to the advanced boot options menu and restart the computer.
Must be used with /r